# HTML editors similar to Android studio design pane

Tags: html, ide

Some time back I used Android studio's UI designer. I liked it a lot since it allows drag and drop of components like buttons/inputs/widget. More importantly,
we can edit the properties of existing UI component like ID/Size/Visibility using its UI pane(see right of the image). This reduces the changes of errors because we dont need to edit it directly into XML file. Also its quite fast.

I am now working now on an web application and need to design HTML page. Could you suggest any software which provides any of the two feature mentioned above for HTML.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Online

- [Mobirise](https://mobirise.com/)
- [Bootstrap Studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io/)
- [Square Space](https://www.squarespace.com/)
- [Wix](http://www.wix.com/)

Idk about desktop apps, But since adobe is always perfect, I think DreamWeaver will surely support that.

Comment: You are right. DreamWeaver is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: glad to help :)